# Nginx ssl connection

Tags: nginx

I am trying to server secure site using nginx ssl connection.I am not able to load third party http css and js file. It is giving error.

```
 This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

here is the my nginx conf

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name api-test.vendorver.com;
ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/vv_key/cert_chain.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/vv_key/vendorver.key;
ssl_protocols    TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
#if ($host !~* ^(vendorver.com|www.vendorver.com)$ ) {
#    return 444;
#}
location /static/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /home/ec2-user/vendorver.backend/static/;
}
}
```

That file is not available on https request. How can i include that file in page?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your static directory and your media (images) directory
To run all this over ssl the config should be something like:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    ssl on;
    listen 443 ssl;


    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/yoursite_com/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/yoursite_com/cert.key;



    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";

    access_log /var/www/vhosts/yoursite.com/logs/access_log;
    error_log  /var/www/vhosts/yoursite.com/logs/error_log;
    server_name yousite.com www.yoursite.com;

    root /var/www/vhosts/yoursite.com/yourapp/;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;


    location / {
          .... your settings here
    }
    location /media {
        alias /var/www/vhosts/yoursite.com/yourapp/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/vhosts/yoursite.com/yourapp/static;
    }
    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than listening to both ports 80 and 443 in the same config. I suggest setting up server redirects, e.g.

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name endyourif.com www.endyourif.com;
   return 301 https://www.endyourif.com$request_uri;
}
```

[Setting up SSL with nginx including redirects from non HTTPS traffic](https://www.endyourif.com/setting-up-ssl-with-nginx-including-redirects-from-non-https-traffic/)